# Unable Override onCreateOptionsMenu in my Main_Activity

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, oncreateoptionsmenu

Two days ago, I switched switched from xamarin to android studio and I'm extremly new to Java. I'm trying to create a `DrawerLayout` with a `NavigationView` but once I try to override `onOptionsItemSelected` it simply don't wanna come. So what should I do? I tried to paste a method, but android studio treats it as a normal variable or method.

Edit : Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is a method like `onCreate()`. You have to write this method in the same level of your `onCreate()` and not inside. To do this, move onCreateOptionsMenu() below the very next closing brace.

Comment: You can also try to reformat your code with android studio to see much clear

Comment: Oh thanks man i didn't notice the curly braces tbh  i really appreciate that ❤

Answer (score 0):

onCreateOptionMenu() is same as onCreate() method, you have to write down this method below one more "curly braces".

It solve your problem.